# tensorflow-gpu can't execute certain cells as t = tf.Variable(5), but detects my gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Here are my specs :

Ubuntu 20.04

tried tensorflow-gpu version 2.0 to 2.5

cuda and cudnn downloaded with conda : cuda 10.1, cudnn 7.6.5

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPq6NIboLSc (it lasts 5 minutes, and some comments say it works in the past month) step by step, even try the solutions in the comments :

```
conda create -n tfgpu python=3.7
conda activate tfgpu
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.1

pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator
pip uninstall tensorboard 
pip uninstall tensorboard-plugin-wit
pip install tensorflow==2.3
pip check
```

to downgrade to many versions, I have tried all the possible combinations and versions, by rebuilding environments from scratch.

In some versions, tf detects my gpu :

```
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 14590583484823824053
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 7716553310653404229
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 1505951744
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 3827512444124672980
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce 840M, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 5.0"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 11245957731175040440
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]





tf.config.list_physical_devices()

[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'),
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'),
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]




tf.config.list_logical_devices()

[LogicalDevice(name='/device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
 LogicalDevice(name='/device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'),
 LogicalDevice(name='/device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'),
 LogicalDevice(name='/device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]
```

However, when it detects my GPU, there are some cells it doesn't execute, a star '*' stays in the brackets '[]' at the left of the cell and last until I restart the kernel (more than 10 minutes, it is not normal).
For instance when I run `t = tf.Variable(5)`, or when I try to train a model

I am not used to ask without searching, it is the first topic I do because I have spent the last week-end looking for a solution and I need to find it quick since I am in internship

Also, I used the same tutorial on windows 10 and it had worked, but now I am on another laptop from my work, and I don't have my previous one.

If someone that knows how it actually works can spend 5 minutes to follow do the tutorial and explain me what to do to solve it, it would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous solution was deleted I am sorry I am new to stackoverflow

I got a solution using docker to create an 'Image' and then a 'container' to run tensorflow 2.4.0 on my gpu. A friend of mine succeded to install it on my linux 20.04 os

I let his very useful website here if anyone gets the same problem as me, everything you need is indicated : https://dinhanhthi.com/docker/

All you need to do is copy/ paste the commands one by one in your terminal:

Firstly the third paragraph which is 'installation'

Then the sixth to check whether everything has gone right

Then build an 'image' with the nineth and a 'container' with the tenth
An image is kind of like a virtual machine, like when you create a virtual linux distribution from windows.
A container is more like an anaconda environment you can custom in order not to recreate an image from scratch every time (an image is about 7GO heavy)

After that go to https://dinhanhthi.com/docker-gpu/#install-nvidia-docker2 and folow the 3rd 4th and 5th steps to install docker-gpu, check the installation and install nvidia docker-2

Once everythong is done, all you have to do when you start your computer is

```
# Start your computer# Check if docker is running
docker ps
# if something like below comes out, it's running
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES# 
#Run the container
docker start docker_ai
# If you wanna check currently running containers
docker ps
# Stop container
docker stop docker_ai
# Enter the running container (to install packages, 
#for example)
docker exec -it <container_name> bash
# Inside this, if you wanna install some package, use pip
pip install <package_name>
```

Comment: The links to dinhanhthi.com have changed, they're now: https://dinhanhthi.com/note/docker/ and https://dinhanhthi.com/note/docker-gpu/